# Why my code not working appending the values to key

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

My code is below, just trying to implement `defaultdict`

```
out = defaultdict(list)
testdict = [{'local': '9134567890'},
{'local': '9134567890'},
{'global': '0134567890'},
{'others': '9034567890'},
{'others': '9034590'}]
for s in testdict:
    for k,v in s.items():
            out[k].append(out[v])   
out
```

Output

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'0134567890': [],
             '9034567890': [],
             '9034590': [],
             '9134567890': [],
             'global': [[]],
             'local': [[], []],
             'others': [[], []]})
```

Desired OUt

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'local': ['9134567890', '9134567890'], 'global': ['0134567890'], 'others': ['9034567890', '9034590']})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending `out[v]` instead of just `v`. You meant to do this:

```
for s in testdict:
    for k,v in s.items():
            out[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

`out[v]` will always return an empty `list`. Replace it with `v`:

```
...
out[k].append(out[v])
```

The value of `out` will be then:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'global': ['0134567890'], 'local': ['9134567890', '9134567890'], 'others': ['9034567890', '9034590']})
```